# Alguém sabe onde eu consigo encontrar material para por barra de ferramentas em um TextArea, para usar com php na área de postagem?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: Exemplo: Essa barra de ferramentas]

Eu quero por uma barra de ferramentas nesse estilo em um text area, para usar para estilização de artigos para postagens, alguém pode me dizer onde encontro material, ou por ventura, ja ensinar ou mandar algum código para eu analisar e tal para refazer?

Comment: Procure por "WYSIWYG HTML Editor" no Google. Vai aparecer alguns famosos como TinyMCE, Summernote, CKEditor entre outros.

Comment: google ckeditor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.tinymce.com/

Para usar é simples, basta adicionar esse script no seu código:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script><script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
```

Esse script fará com que todos os teus inputs com a tag `textarea` já fiquem com o editor.